# Connect to a specific lotus notes database/documen via vba

Tags: vba, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I can connect to lotus notes via the following code. So basically I connect to the database: `CLASTNAME/O=TEST/C=US.nsf`

```
Set oSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Server = oSession.GetEnvironmentString("MailServer", True)

UserName = oSession.UserName
MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"

'Open the mail database in notes
Set db = oSession.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)

Set view = db.GetView("Customers") //ERROR
```

However, I want to connect to a specific database, which I have. Here is the document link:

```
<NDL>
<REPLICA C1451C8A:00575D55>
<VIEW OD3B89A25B:7D1FR7SA-OM4923732F:011L111C>
<NOTE OFAAAA64WE:GH1Q0W0W-IUZ0987MNB:2222F4LÖ>
<HINT>CN=ZZZUSDMS09/O=ZZZ/C=US</HINT>
<REM>Database 'UserName', View 'Customers', Document 'AG: A list of all company customers, Jannuary 9, 2009'</REM>
</NDL>
```

This is what I tried:

```
Sub notesBB()
    'Const DATABASE = ""
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim db As Object
    Dim view As Object
    Dim Entry As Object
    Dim nav As Object
    Dim oSession As Object   'The notes session
    Dim nam As Object       ' notes username
    Dim v() As Variant      ' to hold the subtotal values
    Dim bills(12, 16)       ' 12 months, 16 departments
    r = 1
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z99").Clear

    '##############################
    'Start a session to notes
    Set oSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    Server = oSession.GetEnvironmentString("MailServer", True)

    UserName = "CN=ZZZUSDMS09/O=ZZZ/C=US" 'oSession.UserName
    CustomerDbName = "CZZZUSDMS09/O=ZZZ/C=US" & ".nsf"
    'Open the mail database in notes
    Set db = oSession.GETDATABASE("", CustomerDbName)

    Set view = db.GetView("OD3B89A25B:7D1FR7SA-OM4923732F:011L111C")
    view.AutoUpdate = True // here I get an error
    Set nav = view.CreateViewNav 
    Set Entry = nav.GetFirst
    Do Until Entry Is Nothing
    If Entry.isCategory Then
        r = r + 1
        v = Entry.ColumnValues
        For i = 1 To 16
        bills(v(0), i) = v(4 + i)
        Cells(4 + r, 2 + i) = bills(v(0), i)
        Next
    End If
    Set Entry = nav.getNextCategory(Entry)
    DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

However, as you can see I get an error hee: `view.AutoUpdate = True // here I get an error`

How to connect to this database via vba?

I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Well, this doesn't look right:

```
CustomerDbName = "CZZZUSDMS09/O=ZZZ/C=US" & ".nsf"
'Open the mail database in notes
Set db = oSession.GETDATABASE("", CustomerDbName)
```

You're just appending ".nsf" to the user's fully disntinguished name in canonical form, and that would be an extremely unusual naming convention for databases on a server.  Also, earlier in your code you retrieved the server name, but here you're specifying "" for the server name instead of using what you had retrieved, so the result is that the code will try to open the database on the local machine.

The NDL file is giving you the ReplicaID of the database here:

```
<REPLICA C1451C8A:00575D55>
```

You can use the [OpenByReplicalID](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_OPENBYREPLICAID_METHOD.html) method instead:

```
repID = "C1451C8A00575D55"         ' note that the : is removed
'Open the database by replica id 
set db = new NotesDatabase("","")
If db.OpenByReplicaID( , "85255FA900747B84" ) Then
   Print( db.Title & " was successfully opened" )
Else
   Print( "Unable to open database" )
End If
```

The next problem, though, is that the NDL file is giving the view's UNID, not its name

```
<VIEW OD3B89A25B:7D1FR7SA-OM4923732F:011L111C>
```

There is no call in the Notes COM API that can retrieve a view by its UNID; you need the name for that.  But do you really need to get the view? The NDL gives you the UNID of the document, here:

```
<NOTE OFAAAA64WE:GH1Q0W0W-IUZ0987MNB:2222F4LÖ>
```

So if your goal is to just get the specific document specified in the NDL, you can use a call to [GetDocumentByUNID](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETDOCUMENTBYUNID_METHOD.html).  Note, however that the actual UNID consists of only the 17 chars to the right of OF in the above tag, minus the : char.  So your code would look like this:

```
unid = "AAAA64WEGH1Q0W0W" ' see note below!!
Set doc = db.GetDocumentByUnid(unid)
```

BTW, that UNID does not look legal. The chars should be hex, and the W, Q, and G are not. I'm going on the assumption that you (or someone) deliberately obfuscated the data in your NDL file.

If you do need to access the view, the [NotesNoteCollection](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESNOTECOLLECTION_CLASS.html) class may provide a way to get there, but it will not be trivial.

Finally, you may find this [code from Stepehn Wissel](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-79CNKF) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just tried your code, however I get a compiler error at this line `set db = new NotesDatabase("","")`. You are right I changed some letters in the code to obfuscate my companes database. What my overall goal is to retrieve data from this database/view and show them in excel. This would be extremely great!!!!

Comment: Btw what is this number? `"85255FA900747B84"`?

Comment: It's the actual UNID. (Or replicaID - I can't see where you pulled that from. Too difficult to see context from my phone.)

Answer (score 1):

Specify the name of the view instead:

```
Set view = db.GetView("Customer")
```

Comment: Is that really the name of the view? In the first example it was Customers.

Comment: Yep its Customers, as I can see from the definition of the direct link. What could  check to make it work and how?

Comment: That's the view's UNID that you see in the VIEW tag of NDL file, not the name. The name is in the comment line - the one that begins with REM, but that may or may not be reliable. Also, the information from the HINT portion of the NDL is not necessarily the actual database name.

Answer (score 1):

Nice to see my code getting recycled !  it seems to me that you aren't using the correct database and view names.  Are they not 
Database 'UserName', and View 'Customers' ? (from your link).   Whatever  - when your XL VBA crashes out, in the Debug - Locals window, look for the object(s) that you have tried to instantiate with the SET command.  If they show up as "nothing", you've got the SET command(s) wrong and trying to use the failed object (view) then crashes on the following line.

If your servername is "Yoda" I'd guess you need

```
Set db = session.getdatabase("Yoda", "Username.nsf")
Set view = db.GetView("Customers")
```